# Validate correlative numbers using Regular Expressions in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to write a regular expression to validate a password, and I'm struggling with this point in particular.

I want to prevent users from using correlative numbers like:

```
123456 or 34567 or 6789
```

and also repeated numbers like

```
111111 or 3333 or 2222 or 9999
```

I tried reading and using an online regex tool but I'd really appreciate some assistance with this.

Notes: I want to allow users to include correlative and repeated segments in the password. The following inputs should pass my validation:

```
qwerty1234 hidude222 weirdp455
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I want to prevent users from using correlative numbers` , `Notes: I want to allow users to include correlative and repeated segments in the password.`

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: could you explain the difference between the two? Did you want to allow or not allow?

Comment: I doubt that you can do this with one regular expression. If you can, it will be a monster. Better to use a sequence of well defined tests that use an appropriate mechanism, which might be a regular expression or might not.

Comment: could you post some valid and invalid examples?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: It probably means that a password like `123456789` is not allowed, but a password like `abcdef123456789` is allowed. As long as the whole password is not one single pattern, it seems that OP wants to allow them.

Comment: nhahtdh got it right.

Comment: I've tried sequential regexs like cfq answer but I'm looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: I've read.about the (.) regex operator and I think it could be achieved using it but I've failed miserably so far

Comment: I'm asking what characters are allowed?

Comment: Numbers letters only, but just focus on excluding a whole correlative input. Just that.

Comment: Would [this](https://regex101.com/r/eD2tL8/1) help you out? An [example](https://eval.in/282154) ...

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you

```
thenums = "4567";
if (thenums.match(/(0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|7890|(\d)\2\2\2)/)) {
    alert("bad number sequence, bad!");
}
```

This looks for 4 digit sequential strings or 4 same-digit strings anywhere within your variable. If you want to match the entire string you can do

```
thenums = "4567";
if (thenums.match(/^(0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|7890|(\d)\2\2\2)$/)) {
    alert("bad number sequence, bad!");
}
```

If you'd prefer to trip on three-digit repetitions, you can remove one of the `\2`s.

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qq7mr98a/)

Update, fiddling with this, I made this regex that will search for a string containing sequential numbers if it matches the whole string.

```
^(0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9)))))))))|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0)))))))))|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1)))))))))|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2)))))))))|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3)))))))))|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4)))))))))|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5)))))))))|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6)))))))))|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7)))))))))|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8))))))))))+$
```

And a formatted version, for your viewing pleasure.

```
^(0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9)))))))))
|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0)))))))))
|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1)))))))))
|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2)))))))))
|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3)))))))))
|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4)))))))))
|6(?=$|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5)))))))))
|7(?=$|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6)))))))))
|8(?=$|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7)))))))))
|9(?=$|0(?=$|1(?=$|2(?=$|3(?=$|4(?=$|5(?=$|6(?=$|7(?=$|8))))))))))+$
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this but I want to solve this in a less verbose way. I mean no disrespect, and I thank you for your time.